# Populate text boxes from List Values

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list that is created from a LINQ to XML query. The list can contain 1, 2, 3 or 4 values. I have four text boxes on the form that should be populated based on the values in the List, but I can't figure out how to do this because the number of elements in the list will vary. Would it be better to dynamically create the textboxes based on the number of values in the list? How could I go about this?

It seems like this would be a fairly common task, but I have not been able to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it always going to be less or equal to 4 values?

Comment: Yes, you should dynamically create textboxes and give them some unique names for identification.

Comment: if the number of elements is variable maybe a datagridview or a listview would be better for your use

Comment: @tariq I don't know if that is always true. Sometimes it is good to have a consistent interface. Just a thought. You may very well be right in this case though. It is hard to tell. More of a ux.stackexchange issue though.

Comment: Yes, it will always 4 or less values.

Comment: @TimKennedy, then u can have either static 4 textboxes or dynamic as you like. Had there been many then you should have gone dynamic

Comment: If you have static boxes, you may wish to disable the ones not populated to help the user.  I second the idea of looking into datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating dynamically, or just populating an existing 4, it doesn't matter. Choose which one is best for your UI requirements. (maybe even a DGV as has been suggested already)

First you need something to contain the controls, lets say you have a panel called `MyPanel` which will hold only these textboxes and nothing else...

Here's the load dynamically approach:

```
MyPanel.Controls.Clear();
int count = 1;
foreach(var item in listOfValues)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Name = "MyTextbox" + i;
    tb.Text = item.ToString();//or whatever property you have for the value
    tb.Location = new Point(0, 0 + (25 * (i - 1)));
    MyPanel.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

---

Here is the fill existing approach, assuming you have 4 TextBoxes called "TextBox1" for example:

```
int count = 1;
foreach(var item in listOfValues)
{
    TextBox tb = MyPanel.Controls.Find("TextBox" + i) as TextBox;
    tb.Text = item.ToString();//or whatever property you have for the value
}
```

NOTE: You need to be sure that listOfItems does not contain more items than you have textboxes for, otherwise you will get an exception

Comment: Thanks musefan, I was able to use the second approach to accomplish what I needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a foreach loop and iterate round the linq query creating a new text box on each one and adding it to your form. It'd help to see what you've got so far. I've put an example below using a list instead of a linq query but what comes after it is the same

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newList= new List<string> {"box1", "box2", "box3"};

        foreach (var boxName in newList)
        {
            TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
            newTextBox.Text = boxName;
            this.Controls.Add(newTextBox);
        }
    }
```

Comment: agreed but I'm not currently able to comment on all posts. I'll also add some supporting code to make it more like a proper answer

Comment: @RyanHird Probably not the best place to say this, but linking your account on another stackexchange will get you 100 rep. http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: For the 1st one you enroll to the 100 rep would be added to your SO account but for the rest it would be added to whatever SE category you enrolled to normally as 101 rep (100 + 1 default rep).

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a List

```
       List<int> testList = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
       foreach(int i in testList)
        {
          TextBox test = new TextBox();
          test1.Name = "textBox"+i;
           youcOntrl.Controls.Add(test1);
         }
```

You can also give them their location and size etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 4 text boxes in the forms designer and set their `Visible` property to be false as default (from the properties pane).

Then, you can switch on the count property of your list as follows:

```
switch (els.Count)
{
    case 1:
        textBox1.Text = els[1].Value;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        break;
    case 2:
        textBox1.Text = els[1].Value;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Text = els[2].Value;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        break;
    case 3:
        textBox1.Text = els[1].Value;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Text = els[2].Value;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Text = els[3].Value;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        break;
    case 4:
        textBox1.Text = els[1].Value;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Text = els[2].Value;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Text = els[3].Value;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Text = els[4].Value;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

If your list is `IEnumerable`, then you must first call the `ToList()` method on it to get a `List<XElement>` as IEnumerable type does not have a `Count` property.

Comment: Thanks, I considered an approach like this but I was hoping there was something more "elegant". :)

Comment: An elegant approach would be to use something like a `FlowLayoutPanel`. Let me know if you need a code for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is four or less then you don't have to create dynamically the textboxes. You could probably disable the textbox(es) that could not be populated. And specially if you name your textbox sequentially like TextBox1, TextBox2 etc then you could probably code like:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
         if (i <= list.Count)
            { 
              this.Controls["TextBox"+i.ToString()].Text = list[i-1];
              this.Controls["TextBox"+i.ToString()].Enabled = True;
             }
         else
             {
               this.Controls["TextBox"+i.ToString()].Enabled = False;
             }                 
    }
```

So, if you have 2 Items in your List for example then List.Count is 2 and therefore Textbox1 and 2 would be populated and TextBox3 and 4 will be disabled.